# Binding to a Separate DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a MainWindow that contains a window with a TreeView. The tree view binds to an observable collection that I set in the `DataContext`.

```
                    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Trees}"  Name="fileTree" MouseDoubleClick="FileTreeMouseDoubleClick" SelectedValuePath="NodePath">
                        <TreeView.Resources>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeNodeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </TreeView.Resources>
                    </TreeView>
```

However, I want to put a separate tree as a child of the MainWindow, which will bind to a different object, how can I do that If I have already used the `DataContext` property of the `MainWindow.xaml`?

**EDIT: Extension to Question**

Now I have:

```
<TreeView Name="viewTree" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewListTrees, Source=viewListTreeViewModel}">
```

Where `viewListTreeViewModel` is a member variable in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
private ViewListTreeViewModel viewListTreeViewModel;
```

which has the following accessor:

```
    public ObservableCollection<ViewListTreeNodeViewModel> ViewListTrees
    {
        get { return this.tree; }
    }
```

and `ViewListTreeNodeViewModel` has:

```
    public string NodeName { get; }

    public string NodeImage { get; }
```

My hierarchical data template now looks like:

```
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewListTreeNodeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding NodeImage}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NodeName}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply expose two Properties on a class you bind to your Window (rather than binding the collection directly), exposing `ObservableCollection` properties;  `Trees` and `SeperateTree` and bind each TreeView accordingly:

```
<Window>
  <Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Trees}">
      ...
    </TreeView>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding SeperateTree}">
      ...
    </TreeView>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either bind directly to the object using the `Source` part of the `Binding` **or** you can set another `DataContext` locally on the `TreeView`.

**Example 1**

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Trees, Source=YourOtherDataContext}"/>
```

**Example 2**

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Trees}" 
          DataContext="{Binding Path=YourOtherDataContext}"/>
```

---

As promised in the comments, here is an example of a base class to use for your view models.

**Usage**

```
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set { SetValue(ref name, value, "Name"); }
}
```

**ObservableObject**

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Compares the value and sets iff it has changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="field">The field.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
    /// <returns><c>True</c> if the field was changed</returns>
    protected virtual bool SetValue<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        return SetValue(ref field, value, propertyName, true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compares the value and sets iff it has changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="field">The field.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
    /// <param name="checkForEquality">if set to <c>true</c> [check for equality].</param>
    /// <returns><c>True</c> if the field was changed</returns>
    protected virtual bool SetValue<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName, bool checkForEquality)
    {
        if (checkForEquality && EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;

        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="setAction">The set action.</param>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual bool SetValue(Action setAction, string propertyName)
    {
        return SetValue(setAction, null, propertyName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="setAction">The set action.</param>
    /// <param name="equalityFunc">The equality func.</param>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual bool SetValue(Action setAction, Func<bool> equalityFunc, string propertyName)
    {
        if (equalityFunc != null && !equalityFunc.Invoke())
            return false;

        setAction.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(this, propertyName);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(object source, string propertyName)
    {
        // copying the event handlers before that this is "thread safe"
        // http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say you can set another `DataContext` can that be any member variable in the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` class?

Comment: Yes. It has to be a public property. Remember to hook up property changed events if you want your bindings to work.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on how to set "property changed events"? Is that the DataContextChanged event for the TreeView? I have implemented Example 1 in your answer.

Comment: Should the object implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @Seth: Yes. If you are not using *Dependency Properties* You need to notify the `Binding` that your property has changed. ... I will update my answer with a nice example on how to achieve this.